# We were not able to estimate gas contract solidity in testnet working, but in mainnet not work

Tags: solidity, blockchain, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets

We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail.

function minterMint(
address to,
uint256 quantity,
address payee,
uint256 price
) external payable {

```
    require(maxSupply >= totalSupply() + quantity, "insufficent supply");
    require(!paused, "mint is paused");
    require(msg.value >= unitPrice * quantity, "insufficent balance");
    require(payeeAddress == payee, "invalid payee address");
    payable(payeeAddress).transfer(price);
    _mint(to, quantity);
}
```

Comment: Most likely the constructor reverts.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen you mean  constructor contract reverts?
   constructor(
        string memory _name, 
        string memory _symbol
    ) 
    ERC721A(_name, _symbol) 
    {
      
    }

Comment: Constructor code

Comment: @LauriPeltonen this ERC721A I'm reproducing